# How do I change the icon size (zoom) in Files

Tags: pantheon-files, icons

How do I change the icon size in Files?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> To zoom in Files you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + the scroll wheel on your mouse.
> — [fuumind](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/1087/227)

If you don't have a mousewheel you can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>.

(unfortunately not with number pad keys)

Comment: Can you modify your answer to include the scroll wheel information as well? In this way, we can have a single vote-able best answer instead of multiple "best" answers. Thanks!

Comment: That would be ok with me.

Comment: I modified my answer.

Answer (score 5):

To zoom in Files you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + the scroll wheel on your mouse.